# Elegant way to capture exit code of command in a set -e script

Tags: bash

I have a script usually running under `set -e` (specifically, `set -euo pipefail`).

One particular command, `grep`, I expect to sometimes return a non-zero exit code and I want to take some action depending on the specific return code rather than simply whether the command failed<sup>1</sup>.

Something like:

```sh
grep ...
if [[ $? -eq ... ]]; then
  ...
fi
```

This will fail under `set -e` if `grep` returns a non-zero exit code, so I'll never get to my `if`. I can't just run it directly in the `if` like `if grep ...; then` since I care about more than just 0 and non-zero.

I don't want to disable `set -e` temporarily as this is ganky and clobbers the e state in case I wasn't running under `set -e` in the first place.

This is what I came up with:

```sh
{ grep ...; gexit=$?; } || true
if [[ $gexit -eq ... ]]; then
...
```

Certainly there must be something better?

---

<sup>1</sup> Specifically, `grep` is a bit unusual in that it returns an exit code of 0, 1 or 2 for "1+ matches", "0 matches" and "error", respectively. I'm not looking for a grep-specific answer, however.

Answer (score 3):

Depends on how you define elegant. This is elegant to me:

```
if
  grep ...
  [[ $? -eq ... ]]
then
  ...
```

But not very useful, as the exit status of `grep` is immediately lost and can't be examined any further. This, on the other hand, doesn't have that problem:

```
if grep ...; then
  # handle zero
  ...
else
  # handle non-zero
  case $? in
  ...)
    ...
  esac
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

> This will fail under set -e if grep returns a non-zero exit code, so I'll never get to my `if`

Testing the `grep` command and it's arguments inside the `if` statement does not exit immediately with `set -e` enabled even if the exit status of `grep` is non-zero

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

set -e

if grep -q somestring somefile; then
  echo good
else
  echo bad
fi
```

---

I've tested both with `bash` and `dash`.

Comment: As I mentioned in the question, I don't just want to test the result of `grep` in a 0/non-zero sense because grep is weird and uses multiple exit codes (0, 1 and 2) to mean different things. So I want to capture the exact exit code so I can do further comparisons. I updated the question to make this clearer.